# Need help in the described Issue

Tags: apex

I have a custom object "**Case Status History** (CSH)(Name as Auto-number type)" which is the Child of **"Case Object"**. I have a field "Response Number" on the custom object. Now I want to have the numbers as 1,2,3,4.... in this field for every record created . Means every time a **"Case Status History"** record is created for a particular case , I want this value to increase by 1. Consider Case A & case B. I want the records and fields values something like below.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this ? Let me know if there is any confusion related to the requirement.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the requirement is clear, what isn't clear is what you have tried so far & what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I was trying to create a formula field . But couldn't figure out how to go with it. I am now trying the trigger approach but I want to avoid it since already I have lots of updates done via trigger. So I am looking for some solution if possible which can be done without Apex.

Comment: I can't test at the moment, but I wonder if in the default value for that field you could use a formula to reference a roll up summary field on the parent (case) object to get the count of existing history entries, +1 ?  Just not sure if yo can access roll up summary fields in default values...